# Do your NOTES count toward the Clipping Export Limit on amazon kindle?

Tags: kindle-cloud-reader

I'm trying to export my highlights from my Kindle book.
Running up against the Export Limit (5% for this book).

Do my NOTES count toward that limit?
If they don't, I can change some of my highlights to just notes (describe the section rather than highlight it).

Comment: what limit?? local storage? cloud? this is for **one** book you have notes on??

Comment: Kindle Export limit. It's a limit, set by author, of how much can be exported from a book. At the extreme, you could export the entire book without any limits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the [export limit](http://www.edukindle.com/2015/11/is-your-clipping-limit-exceeded/):

> However, there is a bit of a glitch. Amazon will only store and show a
>   limited number of my “clippings” from the book on my Kindle page
>   (kindle.amazon.com). Publishers and authors are rightfully wary of
>   people clipping an outsized portion of the book and displaying it
>   online.

but you can just [copy](https://the-digital-reader.com/2015/02/21/how-to-download-your-kindle-notes-and-highlights-and-export-them/) `My Clippings.txt` via USB cable.  Also, you can share on twitter or facebook quite easily.

For Kindle books you should be able to e-mail notes to yourself.

On Linux:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /media/thufir/Kindle/documents/My\ Clippings.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 82597 Mar 26 15:31 /media/thufir/Kindle/documents/My Clippings.txt
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tree /media/thufir/Kindle/documents/My\ Clippings.sdr/
/media/thufir/Kindle/documents/My Clippings.sdr/
├── My Clippings2c160740cd13972662f6cb2a18bbd068.mbp1
└── My Clippings2c160740cd13972662f6cb2a18bbd068.mbs

0 directories, 2 files
thufir@dur:~$
```